# OpenGattServer returns null

Tags: android

In my Android application, I have the following code:

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(BluetoothManager)));

_bluetoothGattServer = bluetoothManager.OpenGattServer(Android.App.Application.Context, _customBluetoothGattServerCallback);

// _bluetoothGattServer is always null now
```

Before it would work every time, but after a few changes in my app, `OpenGattServer` always returns null now. The only difference that I think could be relevant is that before I was calling this code on a button-clicked event, but now I am calling this code on a different thread, invoked from a `Timer`.

In case that it's because of a thread issue, is there a way to force this code to run on the UI thread? (or whatever appropriate thread)

Note: I'm writing this app in Xamarin.Android, but an answer in native Android would work for me.

Comment: From your `Activity` call `runOnUiThread()`. Else, you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917308/how-to-post-toast-from-non-ui-widget-thread/39917437#39917437 which can be used from anywhere without needing access to an `Activity`.

Comment: That worked. So `OpenGattServer` should not be called from a different thread.

Comment: Glad it worked! Moving it to a proper answer. Could you mark it as the solution? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your tests, it must be called from the `UiThread`.

So, the solutions are:

- From your `Activity` call `runOnUiThread()`.
- Else, you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917308/how-to-post-toast-from-non-ui-widget-thread/39917437#39917437) which can be used from anywhere without needing access to an `Activity`.